# The meaning of the $\alpha$ helix and $\beta$ sheets in proteins

Tags: proteins, protein-folding, protein-structure, definitions

I asked this question to my Biology teacher and he, in collaboration with a Chemistry teacher, couldn't find the answer. My question is the following: "What does the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ represent in the secondary structure of a protein? I do reference to the $\alpha$ helix and $\beta$ sheets in proteins." I had a similar question with the glucose and we concluded that it was related to the Chemistry, the $\alpha$ or $\beta$, was related with the functional groups bonded to the carbon.

Comment: use of term alpha and beta for *protein-chain-folding* is **completely unrelated** with alpha and beta forms of *ring-form monosaccharide*. A polypeptide chain can form a spring-shape that is called alpha-helix. A polypeptide can also fold into a flat sheet whose folding pattern is known as beta sheet.

Comment: Related http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/45735/3340

Comment: To add to the confusion, there is also "alpha sheet", which is rarer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_sheet and the "beta helix" fold https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_helix

Comment: @gilleain Yes, that what I want, I would like to know why the $\alpha$-helix is not name "$\beta$-helix"? There must be a certain meaning of the $\alpha$ and $\beta$!

Comment: @Matt - Read WYSIWYG's link. It's really just an arbitrary label. The page for alpha-helix mentions William Astbury as calling the helix "the alpha-form" so presumably it's his fault!

Comment: @gilleain The problem with this answer is that it is a kind of an "easy" answer; ["They are **sometimes** used in science to enumerate or **differentiate** between a **series of related things** — proteins, small molecules etc."] the answer had never explained the difference, it just says that the use of the Greek letter is used to differentiate the thing, but why a specific helix can be $\alpha$ and the other one is $\beta$? Also, to admit the answer, do you have any reference?

Comment: @WYSIWYG, Would it be possible to get a reference of your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple. As described in the accepted answer to the [related question about alpha-subunits vs alpha-helices](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/45735/3340) the alpha- and beta- are arbitrary names. It could easily have been 1 and 2 or A and B based on ordering of letters or numbers; indeed, there are "type I" and "type II" turns.

The history, from the wikipedia page on [alpha-helices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix) says:

> In the early 1930s, ... William Astbury initially proposed a kinked-chain structure for the fibers. He later joined other researchers (notably the American chemist Maurice Huggins) in proposing that:
>
> - The unstretched protein molecules formed a helix (which he called the **α-form**)
> - The stretching caused the helix to uncoil, forming an extended state (which he called the **β-form**).

(Emphasis added). In other words, he named the "α-form" first, and considered the "β-form" to be an uncoiled form of the first one. These names later became "α-**helix**" and "β-**sheet**". It could easily have been the other way around.

Indeed there are other types of helix; the [3<sub>10</sub> helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/310_helix) and the [π-helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_helix). If either of these had been discovered first, perhaps they would be the alpha-helix. Of them all, the 3<sub>10</sub> helix has the most 'logical' name as:

> the helix has **three** residues per turn, and ... has **10** atoms in the ring formed by making the hydrogen bond

so [if we followed a similar naming scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix#Geometry_and_hydrogen_bonding), the alpha helix would be a 3.6<sub>13</sub> helix. Admittedly this is a bit of a cumbersome name.

As well there are the [alpha sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_sheet) - a sheet made of helical strands - and the [beta helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_helix) - a helix made of strands. For both of these, the "alpha" and "beta" part of the name has been chosen because of the naming of the original structures they are related to.